# MVC Core Database First - Table and column names letter case

Tags: asp.net-mvc, firebase-realtime-database, asp.net-core

I am new to MVC and created a database with following table and columns:

TableName: tblCat

Column Names: lngCatId, txtTitle

I used below command to create the tables in my project:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "...dbconnection string.." Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

This create table and columns with first letter in Capital.

TableName: TblCat

Column Names: LngCatId, TxtTitle

What should I do to import table and columns with exactly same name as in my database.

Comment: what version of MVC are you using?

Comment: It's .Net Core 2.0

Comment: Please check my answer and check if this works.

Comment: Just add these parameter -e = 'lowerCamelCase' –f = ‘lowerCamelCase’

Comment: did it helped you solve your problem, or if there any other way of doing please also share with us.

Comment: @Rohit, this did not resolve the issue. Infact I get error when tried lowerCamelCase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these methods from the following link [Here](https://gist.github.com/kennykanp/550a21cc4af68072cdfe4ef7b62e337b), in this case the conversion is ToUpper, but you can change ToLower, you can also use the Nuget **Humanizer** for another type of capitalize.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.ToUpperCaseTables();
        modelBuilder.ToUpperCaseColumns();
        // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the parameters for **Scaffold-DbContext**

```
   Scaffold-DbContext "Server=xxxxx;Database=xxxxxx;Trusted_Connection=True;"
    -o "Models/DatabaseModels" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 
    -e = 'lowerCamelCase' –f = ‘lowerCamelCase’
```

Comment: I get below error when executed above code: Scaffold-DbContext : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'e' is ambiguous. Possible matches include: -Environment -ErrorAction -ErrorVariable.
At line:1 char:136
+ ... Core.SqlServer -e = 'lowerCamelCase' –f = 'lowerCamelCase' -OutputDir Models
+                    ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Scaffold-DbContext], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameter,Scaffold-DbContext